# retrive and save EditText onCreate and when kill application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, android-edittext

hi I'm trying to save the EditText widget values in the internal memory of the phone/tablet so that they can be retrieved automatically by the app when it closes or the activity stops. All off this will work using a save button.(The values of the widget are inputed by the user).

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText pH;
Button b1;

public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
public static final String PrimeraHora = "nameKey";

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final EditText pH = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.primeraHora);

    Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.guardarCambios1);

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String ph = pH.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

            editor.putString(PrimeraHora, ph);
            editor.commit();
            editor.apply();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Thanks",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });



}
```

}

Comment: Do you want to save a text from EditText when you close the activity? I understand correctly?

Comment: You are saving it fine. To retrieve it just use `sharedPreferences.getString(PrimeraHora, "not_found")`

Comment: @VladPylyp yes please help me

Comment: @Napster it doesn’t work at all

Comment: @VladPylyp yes that’s what I want

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing this post with any new information you had, or any new code you'd tried would've bumped it to the top of the active queue. I've closed this as a duplicate of the newer one, since you apparently got your answer there, but, in the future, please just edit the original.